# BATCH - error in XLSX sheet when importing %time%

Tags: excel, batch-file, time, zero, hour

I have a little issue when my batch writes the time before 10 AM.
What it does is scan the barcode from a user card and writes date, time and that code into a .csv file, so that it can be imported into a excel file.

here is my code:

```
@echo off
...
:: set /p fname="Digite o nome do arquivo a guardar os logs: "
set fname=refeicao
goto REF

:REF
....
set cod=""
set /p cod="-> "
if /i %cod%=="" goto err
goto ok

:print
echo %date%     %time%  %cod%>>w:\REFEICAO\%fname%.csv
goto REF

:err
....
goto REF

:OK
...
goto print

:qq
exit
```

The problem is that when time is earlier than 10AM, it exports with a space before, let's suppose it's 4 AM. It would be like: " 4:00:00,00" instead of "04:00:00,00"

How could i get rid of that space or turn it into a "0"?

[Actual code inserted - minus irrelevant `echo`s etc.]

Answer (score 1):

```
echo %time: =0%
echo %time: =%
```

The first line changes spaces to 0, the second one removes spaces. Use the one better fits your problem

Comment: that does not work, this is what i get:

 9:28:43,99: =%

Comment: @GabrielRibas, For me it works. What is exactly the code that generated the indicated output?